# DOJO Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

Following code is giving the **DOJO Undefined Error** while i am running it in the *Internet Explorer*.

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js"
 djConfig="parseOnLoad: true,isDebug:false"   ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readFile() { 
      dojo.xhrGet({ 

        url: "http://www.jnerlich.de/servlets/ReturnParameters", 
        handleAs: "text",
        timeout: 5000, 
        load: function(response, ioArgs) { 
            dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = response;             
                      return response; 
        },
        error: function(response, ioArgs) { 
        console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status); 
        dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = 'Loading the ressource from the server did not work';   
        return response; 
          },


        content: {name: "lars", url:"testing" }
        });
      }
  </script>
```

**Error**
I am getting at this point

```
dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = 'Loading the ressource from the server did not work';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of IE?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/DLnVd/1/) works in IE9. Are you sure the `replace` element exists in your DOM?

```
function readFile() {
    var content = {
        name: "lars",
        url: "testing"
    };
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url: "/echo/html/",
        handleAs: "text",
        timeout: 5000,
        load: function (response, ioArgs) {
            console.log("load", arguments);
            dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = response;
            return response;
        },
        error: function (response, ioArgs) {
            console.log("error", arguments);
            console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status);
            dojo.byId("replace").innerHTML = 'Loading the ressource from the server did not work';
            return response;
        },
        content: {
            html: JSON.stringify(content)
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT** - For IE you may need to view in [full screen mode](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/DLnVd/1/embedded/result/), as the regular jsfiddle page won't load correctly in IE8.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Your IE8 must be different from mine then as I can see it working. Are you using full screen mode, as noted in the edit?

Comment: what outcome or result are u getting?i am stuck it is not working at all

Comment: See edit. Make sure you click the full screen mode link in the **EDIT**.

Comment: My firefox mozila version is 20.0.1 but it doesn't work i m stuck nw bcoz i also tried in chrome but things remains same

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you then. My example works in Chrome, IE8, IE9 and Firefox.

Comment: i fixed the error by changing the <script language="text/javascript"> in the first line of code with <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: If the Dojo script didn't load at all then you would have got an error here `dojo.xhrGet`, and not where you mentioned.

Comment: **Thanxs for support pual but i got solved the error as i done mistake in declaring <script language="text/javascript"> which is wrong.instead i used the <script type="text/javascript"> which is correct.In Actual dojo script is working correctly**